# How to retrieve rest of dataframe after a grouping and index by that grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have df with cols:

```
 date         Account  invoice  category    sales
12-01-2019    123      123      exhaust     2200
13-01-2019    124      124      tyres       1300
15-01-2019    234      125      windscreen  4500
16-01-2019    123      134      gearbox     6000
```

I have grouped by account and sales a

```
dfres = df.groupby(['Account'])({'sales': np.sum})
```

I received:

```
          sales
account
123       8200
124       3300
```

I want to now retrieve original df filtered by my grouped details, so a reduced dataset but i now have the same number of rows as original and only retain top 5% of sales for example. How can i remove unwanted accounts?

Ive tried:

```
index_list = res.index.tolist()
newdf = df[df.account.isin(index_list)]
```

Many thanks

Comment: Yes, it is expected, because `dfres = df.groupby(['Account'])({'sales': np.sum})` has all possible `Account` values, so after filter get same df

Comment: Can you add expcted output to question?

Comment: I want retrieve the reduced grouped df but with all the other columns and  filter that by to sales accounts

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data?

Comment: so , if i received newdf

Comment: sales    Category  
account        
123       8200  gearbox
124       3300  windscreen

Comment: Can you edit question?

Comment: Do you want `df['sales'] = df.groupby(['Account'])['sales'].transform('sum')` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the remaining columns, you'll need to tell pandas how to show the rest of the columns once grouped. For example, if you want to keep the information in `invoice` and `category` and `date` as a list of whatever invoices/cats/dates make up that Account sum, then:

```
dfres = df.groupby(['Account']).agg({'sales': np.sum, 'invoice':list, 'category':list, 'date':list})
```

[image]

You could then reset the index to turn it back into a flat dataframe:

```
dfres.reset_index()
```

[image]